# What is the maximum attack a minion can have?

Tags: hearthstone

I am a very curious person, and I was experimenting in-game with Scaled Nightmare. If you don't know, Scaled Nightmare is a 2/8 dragon that doubles its attack every turn, the highest I've gotten being around 1000 or so damage. So, I was wondering, what would be the highest possible amount of damage any one minion could have?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

2147483647 (so 2.1 billion; maximum of a 32 bit signed integer)
After that it loops back to 0.

This was tested a long time ago with health as seen in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8jP58rs_ugw).
Attack behaves the same way.

Should Blizzard ever choose to increase the variable to 64-bit, the maximum would be 2^63 = 9.22 x 10^18 = 9.22 Quadrillion

Comment: Thank you! I will now begin my crusade to achieve this glorious amount of power!

Comment: 9.22 Quadrillion .... just priest things.